# Castle Windsor Build Error

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I can't build Castle Windsor source for SL40. I went to https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Windsor, downloaded latest. Edited ClickToBuild.cmd to read

```
CALL buildscripts\build.cmd SL40 ClickToBuild
```

But I get the following build error:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4
83,9): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Castle.Wi
ndsor.Tests-SL.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specifi
ed a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.
Configuration='SL4-Release'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this
message because you are trying to build a project without a solution fil
e, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn
't exist for this project. [C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\castleproject-Castle
.Windsor-2.5.2-289-g6d036c9\castleproject-Castle.Windsor-6d036c9\src\Cas
tle.Windsor.Tests-SL\Castle.Windsor.Tests-SL.csproj]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to edit anything. Just running `build.cmd SL40` from the project root works for me (of course, make sure you have [Silverlight 4 Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139&displaylang=en) installed)

Comment: That worked, thanks. Problem was that I was using the ClickToBuild file which adds the command line parameter ClickToBuild.